# Using ArcGIS REST Servers with QGIS 3.20 - Server issue or it's me?

Tags: qgis-3, arcgis-rest-api

So I'm trying to connect to this ArcGIS REST MapServer (which is used by colleagues with ArcMap without issues ofc). I have QGIS 3.20, with the fused ArcGIS REST Servers API.

https://sintegram.gov.mt/server/rest/services/Hosted/Ortho_2018/MapServer

I have created a new connection which seems to be recognized (no error message) and it does connect when I click on it in Data Source Manager, but it does nothing, no layers are showing up and nothing is being added.

[image: Adding the new ArcGIS REST connection]

[image: After clicking "connect", the MapServer shows up, but no action can be done]

I can see on the ArcGIS MapServer link (top of post) that there are no layers defined in the MapServer, and I've read somewhere that in order to connect, this service needs layer numbers.

So, is it possible to determine why it is not working? Is it because the ArcGIS MapServer is not configured properly to let such access?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can connect to the URL and get no response in QGIS 3.20, but also if I use a browser, and try links in the page https://sintegram.gov.mt/server/rest/services/Hosted/Ortho_2018/MapServer I get errors, like https://sintegram.gov.mt/server/rest/services/Hosted/Ortho_2018/MapServer/legend ` 
Could not access any server machines. Please contact your system administrator.` or https://sintegram.gov.mt/server/rest/services/Hosted/Ortho_2018/MapServer/tile/0/0/0 `Error: Not Found`. so it looks like server not client issue

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying out and confirming the server issue ! (also for editing OP).